# Recursive function does not recurse

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, recursion, directory

I have defined a function in Python 3...

```
>>> import os
>>> def find(path):
...   if not os.path.isdir(path):
...     return []
...   out_list = []
...   for f in os.listdir(path):
...     if os.path.isdir(f):
...       for g in find(f):
...         out_list.append(g)
...     else:
...       out_list.append(f)
...   return out_list
...
```

It seems like this would crawl down the tree of `path` and list every file (to me anyway), but when I execute it...

```
>>> find('..')
['CDB', 'dv', 'DataIntegrityUtility', 'cdb', 'libvrs']
```

All the results there are directories which contain files. Should there not be more there?

Comment: Why not make `find` a generator and `yield` the files as you find them?  The code would be simpler and more efficient memory-wise.  And for the times when you must have a list, you can just call `list()` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python there exists `os.walk`.

os.walk('path') => recursively travel the directory, it gives the tuple with directory,

subdirectory and files

```
for x,y,z in os.walk('path'):
    # z is the directory
    # y is subdirectories
    # x is the files
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem is,

```
for f in os.listdir(path):
```

will iterate with the "leaf" names contained in the path, e.g if `path` is '/tmp/foo`and it contains`bar`and`baz`, then`f`will be`bar`, then`baz`.

But then you check if `os.path.isdir('bar')` -- and that means the `'bar'` if any in the current directory, **not** the one under `'/tmp'`!

So you need to add something like

```
f = os.path.join(path, f)
```

just below the `for` statement for the rest of the logic to operate correctly.  (If you do for some reason want just leaf names in `out_list` you can extract them from complete path strings with `os.path.basename`).